# Acces a variable from a C# script from another C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, int, unityscript, var

this is what i have in script A

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class gameController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int Score;
    ...
```

and from another script i want to acces the "Score" variable but i cant figure out how to do it? any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
public int temp =  GameObject.Find("<name of the gaeme object to which your script is attached>").GetComponent<gameController>().Score
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get access of properties/methods of other scripts. you can use 1) Singleton Pattern, 2) Class Object Reference, 3) Properties and many more.

Here are the basic idea of the mentioned 3 ways

1) Singleton Pattern

Define Singlton Instance of Class like below: 
public static gameController Instance;

and use this Instance to get access of score like described below:
gameController.Instance.Score

2) Class Object Reference

get object of the class like below:
public gameController gameControllerObjectRef;

and use the object to get access of the score like described below:
gameControllerObjectRef.Score;

3) Properties

Properties are same as the 2nd way, it just provide better Access Control of class methods/member
Please refer this link for more information about the Properties: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/properties

Hopefully this will help you...

Best,
 Hardik.